# apt-update command not working in parrot security

Tags: parrot-os

The output I receive after `apt update`:

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 4.5 _Parrot_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20190127-02:06] parrot InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 4.5 _Parrot_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20190127-02:06] parrot Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Get:3 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot InRelease [14.6 kB]
Reading package lists... Done    
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 4.5 _Parrot_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20190127-02:06] parrot Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I overcome this ?

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it's difficult for anyone to help you if the question your asking isn't easy to decipher

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the CD-ROM (or or original installation media) from the sources.list

Edit the `sources.list` file with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(comment is a hash (`#`) - so pop one of these at the start of the `deb cdrom: ...` line)

and then try `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly look the [Documentation](https://docs.parrotlinux.org/faq/#how-do-i-upgrade-my-system) regarding how to upgrade the system.

`sudo apt-get` update has been long gone!

Always use

```
sudo parrot-upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```